# How will Perl 6 handle the new combining emoji length?

Tags: unicode, emoji, raku

Some emoji now combine.  For instance, U+1f441 () U+200d (ZWJ) U+1f5e8 () combine to make ‍ ([I am a witness](http://iwitnessbullying.org/)). Rakudo 2016.07.1 on MoarVM 2016.07 says there are two graphemes:

```
> "\x[1f441]\x[200d]\x[1f5e8]".chars
2
```

I think that should be 1.  It seems to have a similar problem with

```
> "\x[1f441]\x[fe0f]\x[200d]\x[1f5e8]\x[fe0f]".chars
2
```

But at least it handles U+fe0f (VS-16, emoji representation) correctly.

Are there plans to fix this in a later version of Perl 6 or am I misunderstanding the intent of the `chars` method?

Comment: [Emoji sequences with ZERO WIDTH JOINER counted as separate chars when they probably shouldn't](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127048#ticket-history) and perhaps [a list of known Perl6 bugs with Unicode tag](http://perl6.fail/t/UNI) may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The ZWJ sequence you mentioned is only part of [Unicode Emoji 4.0](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/4.0/emoji-zwj-sequences.txt) which is still in draft status and planned for release in [November 2016](http://blog.emojipedia.org/whats-planned-for-emoji-4-0/). Under this new version, U+1F5E8 has the Grapheme_Cluster_Break property [E_Base_GAZ (EBG)](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#EBG), so the sequence should indeed form a single grapheme cluster.

I'm sure that Perl 6 will catch up at some point.